# Porque sale WCF de visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, visual-studio-2019, net

Buen dia, tengo una aplicacion en visual studio, que actua como un web service.
El problema y lo curioso es que cuando lo copilo, me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Osea pude trabajar un tiempo sin problemas, pero de un dia para otro me pide esto.
Varios compañeros de trabajo me dicen que hay que "Recopilar y seleccionar el proyecto como principal e inclso reiniciar la compu" y eso les funciona, pero a mi no me a funcionado eso jaja

Saben porque sale esa ventana al copilar? que puedo hacer para que no aparezca y pueda seguir usando mi proyecto.